# How to run Android app on tablet nonstop with display turned on

Tags: android, usb, tablet, battery

I am developing a mobile monitoring system on Android, so I need a platform, that is mobile, lightweighted and that has some computing performance. I have chosen Android, but I've run to a problem that tablet's chargers cant catch up with power consumption.

I can't know for sure how much CPU will application consume (maybe 30%, 40%?), but let's say 100% to be sure.

Is there a way to achieve nonstop run? Maybe tablet with non-usb charger?

edit: Simply speaking I need to charge the device more quickly, then it consume power. Optimization and lowering power consumption by turning down hardware that is not needed right now doesnt seem as a solution since application can be used for entire time...

Comment: I think if you plug your tablet and run your application, it will not give you any problem, until battery life.

Comment: Well... like I've said, our tablets (samsung) consuming power more quickly than chargers are able to provide them with.

Comment: Don't disable your power management. Just because an application runs all the time doesn't mean that optimization can't reduce power by turning off parts of the processor/system. Blocking for I/O and single threading on a multicore machine using intelligent power management will all permit power savings without affecting performance. Also, make sure you aren't polling, a common performance/power consumption mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a a partial WakeLock.

[WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) gives you the ability to stop the device from entering sleep-mode. There are several levels of Wakelock, you are (if I'm correct) interested in turning of the screen to minimize the power consumption but not put the device to sleep and halt computation. For this there is `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`.

Make sure to have the [right permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) for your app before acquiring the WakeLock or you will get a security permission.

Another thing you might want to consider is to use a high-output charger that supplies more than the lowest rated chargers (500mA).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am interested only in nonstop run with display always on. Think of it as a monitor attached to PC. I just need to charge it more quickly :)